# How do you calculate an up vector from pitch, yaw and roll?

Tags: kotlin, math, vector, quaternions

I'm trying to calculate an up vector from a direction vector I have (from which I can get the pitch and yaw) and roll I have. I need this so that I can make a quaternion.

Does anybody know how I can do this?

Comment: A single direction vector isn’t enough information to calculate which way is up. You need to know which way you want to be roughly up. Then you can do a couple of cross products to get the up vector relative to the direction.

Comment: I don't just have the direction vector, I have a separate roll too. I'll look into what you mentioned about cross products too, thank you.

Comment: If you have direction and roll, you can calculate it, so long as you aren't in a gimbal lock orientation (direction pointing straight up or down).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by using a utility that allowed me to convert pitch yaw and roll into an up vector! (Using the quaternions from BKCommonLib)